# Android Emulator and MMS

Tags: android

does android emulator supports MMS messaging? im looking for a solution for my app, please some help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MMS is sent via your cellular carrier. As the emulator doesn't have a cellular connection, you're not going to be able to send/receive messages that way. You'll need a real device for testing that part of your app.

Comment: However for SMS you also need cellular connect and yet you can send it via settings and make a call